# strcpy and string presentation in memory

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, buffer-overflow, strcpy

I have a program like this(x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "123456789";
    char d[] = "123";
    strcpy(d, s);

    printf("%p, %0p\n", s, d);
    printf("%s, %s", s, d);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is : 0xeb6d2930 0xeb6d2910
                    123456789 123456789
I am little confused with the result
I think the program in the memory is like this:

- '9','\0' .  .
- '5','6','7','8'
- 0x7fff813af310: '1','2','3','4'
- 0x7fff813af300: '1','2','3','\0'

so the result should be *s = "789", *d = "123456789"

could you guys explain why the result isn't as I thought?
I changed the format specifier to %p to print the address of d and s 
I know that s and d are overlapped so there is not enough space for d
to hold s which may lead to undefined behaviour,but anyway I was wondering
why the result is *s = "123456789" *d = "123456789"

Comment: `strcpy(d, s);` **BANG** no space in `d` for all of `s`. Your program suffers from [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior).

Comment: Ah yes, the daily "I'm copying stuff into a pointer which isn't pointing at enough valid memory" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output you show the address layout and it's initial content seem to be:

```
       offset 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  
d: 0xeb6d2910 30 31 32 00 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx | 1 2 3 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   0xeb6d2920 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
s: 0xeb6d2930 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 00 xx xx xx xx xx | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . .
```

After the `strcpy(d, s)`:

```
       offset 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  
d: 0xeb6d2910 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 00 xx xx xx xx xx | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . . 
   0xeb6d2920 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
s: 0xeb6d2930 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 00 xx xx xx xx xx | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . .
```

However, as for `d` fewer memory had been allocated as used during `strcpy()` the code invokes undefeind behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior on these two counts:

- Buffer overflow with `strcpy()`: Do not write to memory you do not own.
- Wrong format specifier for `printf()`: Use `%p` to print pointer addresses. Only works for data-pointers though.

Please use the proper prototype for `main`, you nearly have it (this might be UB, though I did not follow all the argument):

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

or compatible or implementation defined extensions are valid.

Undefined Behavior means everything goes, even nasal demons.

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes **undefined behavior** because:
1.  `d` doesn't have enough space to hold the string larger than `4` bytes (including `\0`).
2. You are using wrong format specifier to print the address.

Result is either expected or unexpected.